# Approximation on Inverse Mills ratio for the normal R.V

Tags: normal-distribution, probability-density, cdf, probability-distribution

I've come across several approximations for Mills ratio, but I haven't found any good ones for the Inverse Mills ratio. Is there any known closed-form approximation for the Inverse Mills ratio ([link](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/IMR#:%7E:text=The%20Inverse%20Mills%20Ratio%20(IMR,x)%2Cx%E2%88%88R.)) specifically for a normal random variable, denoted as $\frac{\phi(x)}{\Phi(x)}$ for "$x>0$"? (ratio of normal pdf to normal cdf)

I am expecting to have closed form expression for positive arguments.